# How to use Git push/pull with source(text) files only?

Tags: git

I guess its actually **two questions**:

**(1)** My IDE generates a particular directory structure (which I don't want to alter) with files of different types which are mainly of two kind ... i.e. source(text) vs. binary. I want to work with an online git repository. Whats the best git practice to push/pull only the first kind of files (source/text type) and completely ignore the human non-readable kinds of files like binaries ?

**(2)** Isn't it better and simpler to have all the  project file types generated by my IDE (text + binary) under source control when working with remote repositories as backups etc?

**Note:** I am using msysgit/Gitbash command line git on windows 7 with visualC#/.net and Monodevelop/mono as IDEs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1) You can tell git to simply ignore the binary files by placing expressions in a .gitignore file [as described in the git docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

(2) Typically, it's better to not check in files that are generated by your IDE or build process, since it's easy to regenerate them and it's a maintenance headache when your IDE changes the files between check-ins.